# Sending emails to gmail VIA PHP smtp, hotmail works ok?

Tags: smtp, gmail, laravel

Im trying to send emails form my Laravel application using a Swiftmailer bundle.
My settings are

```
'transports' => array(

    'smtp' => array(
        'host'       => 'server.myserver.com',
        'port'       => 465,
        'username'   => 'info@mywebsite.co.uk',
        'password'   => 'XXXXXXXXX',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ),

    'sendmail' => array(
        'command' => '/user/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ),

    'mail',

),
```

When im sending mail via my application to GMAIL accounts, the server says its send, my WHM email delivery reports says it was successful, but the user never receives the email.
When i test it to hotmail accounts it works fine.

I have mod_ssl and openssl on my server, so it cannot be that, and its sending to hotmail, so i cant see why not gmail?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it works with hotmail, the basic mail procedure is working. So the problem is most certainly on the mailserver. It seems to me, that your mail is classified as spam by gmail and/or other mail services and therefore not delivered. Check if the SMTP server has appropriate DKIM's and SPF records set. Also, check der server logs.

However, I can recommend using a mail API like **[postmark](http://postmarkapp.com)**. No more SMTP trouble. There is a laravel postmark bundle availible, wich makes sending mails a breeze.